# TYPO3 9.5 Include a TypoScript File for all Backend pages

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I did write a Typo3 Extension called 'locationgallery' with a backend Module. This backend module should use the following TypoScript configuration.

```
module.tx_locationgallery_web_locationgallerylocationgallerybe {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:locationgallery/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/
        partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:locationgallery/Resources/Private/Backend/Partials/
        layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:locationgallery/Resources/Private/Backend/Layouts/
    }
}
```

If I now include the static template of 'locationgallery', that was added via `ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile`, anything works fine on each page where this template is included.

My problem is, that I get the error message

```
Sorry, the requested view was not found.

The technical reason is: No template was found. ...
```

if I select a page in the page tree where the static template is not included.

My problem now is that I do not want to include the static template in the root page, but the backend module of 'locationgallery' needs to be usable on all pages.

I did try to include the corresponding parts of the configuration using `ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig`, that is used to add TSConfig to the `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['defaultPageTSconfig']` variable. But this Typoscript is not interpreted before the view tries to find the template. (E.g. it is not interpreted at all during this run, as far as I know, because I found only `TemplateService::mergeConstantsFromPageTSconfig` and `TypoScriptFrontendController::getPagesTSconfig` referring to `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['defaultPageTSconfig']`.)

I found that `powermail` archived what I want by using [ext_typoscript_setup.typoscript](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/FilesAndLocations/), but this is  deprecated according to https://forge.typo3.org/issues/52364.

An additional drawback of this method is that 'ext_typoscript_setup.typoscript' is interpreted independent of backend and frontend mode.

I would like to know if there is any non deprecated method to include some TypoScript for any backend run in Typo3.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You can split your setup into multiple files. E.g. your backend stuff into one (for root page) and your frontend stuff into another.

Comment: @MikelWohlschlegel I already created two Typoscript files (one for the backend and one for the frontend), that are included by the `setup.typoscript`. The problem is that I do not know how to include them independent of each other.

Comment: See my answer. Let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your TS setup into several files to seperate the includes.

Add the following methods in `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_template.php`

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile(
  'your_ext_key',
  'Configuration/TypoScript/backend_or_however_you_call_it.typoscript',
  'Your label'
);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile(
  'your_ext_key',
  'Configuration/TypoScript/frontendend_or_however_you_call_it.typoscript',
  'Your label'
);
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer. Only 2 Points: 1.) I had to use separate Typoscript directories instead of separate files, as the [doc](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_utility_1_1_extension_management_utility.html#a13ee6921557e1123c328a7dd3df9c576) states. 2.) One should definitely use different labels for backend and frontend templates, but I guess this is trivial. Thx for the good answer.